# Loading dynamic images on local devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a cross-platform solution which is written in C# and VS using Xamarin.Forms. At time being, the PCL project is using the WebRequest class with asynchronous mechanisms to fetch images directly from remote server. The PCL project also applies the UriImageSource class to cache a particular image for the first time when it is requested.  However, the solution depends on the speed status of Internet; sometimes it is fast, sometimes it is slow.

Image is not static. It can be changed.

I'd like to change my project in another way. But I am not sure the following way is the right way to go and whether it is possible:

(1) Writing some codes to schedule mobile device (iOS, Android and Win phone) to sync/download images from the server and save images on local mobile device folder (outside embedded folder in the PLC project) **dynamically**.  But is this possible?

(2) If I have images loaded on local mobile devices, how can I fetch such images using methods like ImageSource.FromStream() or ImageSource.FromFile() to show them on Xaml pages? If possible, how can I code?

(3) I am not sure this. If I let image folder of the PCL project to store (assume it is possible) images, then how can I dynamically mark downloaded images as "Embedded Resouce" (Build Actions set). Anyway, I prefer (2) above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) and (2) together is a fairly common approach. You can fetch updated content (images or whatever else) when it is convenient. Android and iOS even have systems for "scheduling" downloads when it's best for the user. See https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/pclstorage for an easy way to read/write files cross platform. See  for an example of using FileImageSource in XAML https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19525/image-source-with-onplatform-in-xaml. (3) is probably not possible because you'd need to edit the DLL in the app bundle which is not allowed.

Comment: @Dylan S. Thank you for your reply. I'll try your hints.